# Using a property to set a property of another object, bad practice?

Tags: c#, properties

Notes:

- Unity3D = Game engine.
- GameObject = Any entity in the game world.
- transform = class used to change scaling, position and rotation of the GameObject.

So I am working on a game with **Unity3D**. I've made a class that, when added to any **GameObject**, gives it the ability to be dragged around the screen.

Now since this is not a Unity3D specific question and rather a C# question, it belongs here, the intro above is just to make things easier to understand and give examples.

The part of the class that is giving me doubts is this one, the rest is irrelevant.

```
public Vector3 Position
{
    get
    {
        return transform.position;
    }
    set
    {
        transform.position = value;
        CallPositionChangedEvent();
    }
}

public Action<Vector3> PositionChanged;

private void CallPositionChangedEvent()
{
    if (PositionChanged != null)
        PositionChanged.Invoke(Position);
}
```

**transform.position** is a property that every GameObject has.

***Real question***: My property **Position** is getting and setting another property from a different class. Is it bad practice?

Comment: This is opinion based-ish, so be careful, it may disappear soon.  But, that works for me. If the `Position` of a `Vector3` is semantically a property of a `Vector3`, and it is calculated by looking at some other property's `position`, then it makes sense to delegate things in the way you do.  Consumers of your class should not need to understand how you calculate position, and you nicely hide it.  Calling something in the property's setter (the way you do) is one of the reasons properties are "run code" things rather than simply "object state" things.

Comment: It is very common to wrap an object inside another class to provide higher level functions and abstractions.

Comment: So we can conclude that it's OK to do that and doesn't cause any harm?
By the way yeah its opinion based but i guess there are general guidelines, do's and dont's for this.

Comment: It is completely OK!